# How to open summary of responses on Google sheets with script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google form that collects a bit of info (of course). In the responses file, I am making a GUI that allows a view to look at the data in different ways. No problem, but I want to create a button in the sheet that when pressed, it opens the "summary of responses". Is this possible with a script? I know how to attach a script to a button I drew, but I can't find anything in the docs for a method that opens the summary page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly. You want a button on your spreadsheet that will open up a dialog with summary statistics of your responses.

I would personally add a menu item to your spreadsheet by adding the following.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Summary of Data", functionName: "dataGUI"},
                      {name: "Other statistics", functionName: "otherGUI"];
  ss.addMenu("Summary Options", menuEntries);
}
```

This will create a menu item that links to whatever function that runs your GUI (assuming that the name of it is "dataGUI")

Comment: Thank you for the response. The option for showing the summary is a default already in the menu ("Form" > "Show Summary of Responses"). I wanted a one button click option to show the responses. Just don't know how to call it (or if it can be)

Comment: I see what you're asking now. You want to open the form statistics through the spreadsheet (they look very handy). I can't say that I know how to link that functionality to a script. It looks like it is displaying it through a separate html page, rather than a GUI....So maybe try and see if it's possible to import the html file into your script? Sorry I can't be more help

Comment: I see what you are suggesting. I'll give it a try. Thank you